# pyside2 QT I have a dotted, white line around the icon labels populating my QListwidget, and I would like to get rid of it

Tags: python, pyside2

I am using Pyside2 and I have a QListWidget populated with icons. The icon labels have a dotted, white line around them. I was hoping to have a cleaner presentation and get rid of that line. I will include a picture.

[image]

Comment: what is the ouput of  `print(QtWidgets.QApplication.style().objectName())`?

Comment: Thank you, I ran the command and got: 'adskdarkflatui'  I am not sure what that means.

Comment: It looks like the style is Autodesk's dark flat UI. You could try setting the app style to a different style, like "Fusion", or you may be able to set the label's focus policy to Qt.NoFocus

Comment: How would I change the app style?  What would be the syntax for that?

Comment: setting the focus of the layout widget did the trick, thank you.

Comment: @winteralfs You can change the app style with `app.setStyle('Fusion')` in the same file that you define `app = QApplication([])`